# We know the number of digits of a number. Which is it?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

Assume we know the number of digits of a number $n \in \mathbb N$ has in some different bases:

$$b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n$$

What is the best approximation or the best "narrowing down" we can make of which number $n$ is?

Comment: This is a little unclear. You know the representations but not which bases they are in? Perhaps give an example to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean something like four decimal and ten binary digits implies $1000\le n\le 1023$?

Comment: I believe the OP is saying that we know the length of each representation, but not the representation itself.  Thus the base $10$ number $2$ is length $1$ in every base but $1$.  Obviously if you know the length of the base $1$ representation you know the number....

Comment: Oh, I see... thanks @lulu!

Comment: @Nilknarf  the question is still not entirely clear to me.  Each length gives you some clear bounds.  If I tell you that my number is length $L$ in base $B>1$ then the least it can be is $B^{L-1}$ and the most it can be is $B^L-1$. So if we have many bases we can look for the intersection of those intervals...

Comment: @lulu Whoah. You said what I just typed in my answer to the question. XD

Comment: @lulu What is still unclear to you, though?

Comment: @Nilknarf  Well, I expect the OP is looking for something else (of course I might be wrong).  Perhaps there is a game theory component...for example, given the answer for base $B_1$, which base $B_2$ should I ask for to maximize information?

Comment: @lulu Hmm, perhaps. That isn't too difficult to determine, though. It's like using a binary search that cuts the number of results in half - just choose the base whose overlap with your current inequality is nearest to half of it.

Comment: @Nilknarf  Right.  But probably I am just over thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the number of digits of a number $n$ in base $k$ representation is, of course,
$$\lfloor \log_k n\rfloor+1$$
Which means that if you were given the number of digits $d$ in a number's base $k$ representation, you could determine that the number $n$ satisfies
$$k^{d-1}\le n \lt k^d$$
And so if you were given this information about $n$ in for multiple bases $$k_1,k_2,...,k_a$$
then you would need to find the solution, or the "overlap", of the system of inequalities
$$k_1^{d-1}\le n \lt k_1^d$$
$$k_2^{d-1}\le n \lt k_2^d$$
$$...$$
$$k_a^{d-1}\le n \lt k_a^d$$
in order to find all possible values of $n$.

For example:

Suppose we are given that $n$ has:

- $9$ digits in binary
- $5$ digits in ternary
- $3$ digits in decimal

Then we can conclude that
$$512\le n\lt 1024$$
$$243\le n\lt 729$$
$$100\le n\lt 1000$$

and so $n$ can be any number in the interval
$$512\le n \lt729$$

If we are given lengths $d_1,...,d_a$ in bases $k_1,...,k_a$, we can only narrow down the *exact* values of $n$ if and only if, for some $d_i,k_i$ and $d_j, k_j$,
$$k_i^{d_i-1}=k_j^{d_j}-2$$
and if no other $d_v, k_v$ satisfy
$$k_v^{d_v-1} \gt k_i^{d_i-1}$$
$$k_v^{d_v} \lt k_j^{d_j}$$
because if this is the case, then we could narrow our conditions down to
$$k_i^{d_i-1}\le n \lt k_j^{d_j}-1$$
$$k_i^{d_i-1}\le n \lt k_i^{d_i-1}+1$$
and conclude that
$$n=k_i^{d_i-1}$$
But, of course, this can only happen if $n$ is a perfect power.